# Hyperjaxb @Entity

Tags: java, jaxb, hyperjaxb

How to avoid declaring fully qualified name of the derived class in @Entity annotation?
I have the following xsd:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Project">
        <xsd:annotation>
                <!-- ... -->
        </xsd:annotation>
 <xsd:sequence>
  <!-- ... -->
 </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

but it generates the following java source:

```
@Entity(name = "com.mycompany.db.Project")
@Table(name = "project")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Project
    implements Equals, HashCode, ToString
{
...
}
```

I need to remove explicitly name from @Entity, to be like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Project
    implements Equals, HashCode, ToString
{
...
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Why? Surely the entity name is largely irrelevant?

Comment: skaffman: Some users reported qualified names aren't actually standard in JPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, Hyperjaxb now has an own tag on SO. :)

In the new version (0.5.5, to be released soon) HJ3 generates non-qualified entity names. See http://jira.highsource.org/browse/HJIII-34.

Comment: @lexicore Can you help me with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34065476/use-fully-qualified-names-in-hyperjaxb3-generated-java-classes) I am using version 0.5.6 but I want to have fully qualified names in `@Entity` name field ?