# use fully qualified names in hyperjaxb3 generated java classes

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jaxb, hyperjaxb

I have generated .java classes from the hyperjax3 which are already annotated with Annotations like **@Entity and @Table** etc.."

In @Entity the class name is automatically added as follows:
`@Entity(name = "MyClassName")`
But I want this name field to have a **fully qualified class name**  as
`@Entity(name = "myPackage.here.MyClassName")`
I am using the
[hyperjaxb3-ejb-samples-po-initial-0.5.6](https://java.net/projects/hj3/sources/svn/show/trunk/ejb/samples/po-initial) example
and generating the annotated java classes by running ***mvn clean install*** where my XSDs schemas are present in the `src\main\resources` folder in maven project.

*I have searched and found a way which states that *use auto-import=false* but I am not able to incorporate this as I am simply running that maven project.

Comment: Please refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572576/hyperjaxb-entity/3184360#comment55884010_3184360) for a similar issue !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of [Hyperjaxb3](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3).

Entity name is not customizable, but you can implement your own naming strategy to generate fully qualified entity names.

For this, you'd have to impement the `org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.ejb.strategy.naming.Naming` interface. The easiest would be to subclass `org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.ejb.strategy.naming.impl.DefaultNaming` and to override the `getEntityName` method:

```
public String getEntityName(Mapping context, Outline outline, NType type) {
    final JType theType = type.toType(outline, Aspect.EXPOSED);
    assert theType instanceof JClass;
    final JClass theClass = (JClass) theType;
    return CodeModelUtils.getPackagedClassName(theClass);
}
```

You'll also have to include the `org\jvnet\hyperjaxb3\ejb\plugin\custom\applicationContext.xml` resource to configure your custom naming strategy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

    <bean name="naming" class="com.acme.foo.CustomNaming">
        <property name="reservedNames" ref="reservedNames"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Finally, compile it all, pack as JAR and add to the HJ3 classpath, for instance via plugin dependencies in the Maven POM:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-hyperjaxb3-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>...</configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.acme.foo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hyperjaxb3-custom-naming-extension</artifactId>
                    <version>...</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Here's a test project which implements/configures a custom naming stratgy:

- https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/tree/master/ejb/tests/custom-naming

See also:

- [Hyperjaxb3 naming strategy configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481023/hyperjaxb3-naming-strategy-configuration)
- http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/Customization+Guide (Server seems to be down at the moment)